# SQL select MAX value from last day

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a table with DateTime and Value columns. I need to select max value from the last day (newest) day. The best I could come up with is 3 step process:

1. `SELECT MAX(DateTime) FROM MyTable`
2. get rid of time part in datetime, store date
3. `SELECT MAX(Value) FROM MyTable WHERE DateTime>date`

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO check the tag

Comment: @swasheck Thanks. At least someone around here knows what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your three steps in one query would be

```
SELECT MAX(Value)
FROM MyTable
WHERE DateTime >= CAST( (SELECT MAX(DateTime)FROM MyTable) AS DATE)
```

Now finding the max date could be quite expensive query so if you're actually after the yesterday's max value then you should use `CURRENT_DATE` instead, ie

```
WHERE DateTime >= ( CURRENT_DATE - 1 ) AND DateTime < CURRENT_DATE
```

Comment: That condition will also select fields of today (or tomorrow).

Comment: Since we're selecting the max date there can be no "tomorrow's records". But the query with CURRENT_DATE needs to be fixed, thats, right.

Comment: Thank you @ain ! The trick with CAST was what I was looking for.

Comment: @ain That depends on what is in `DateTime`, it could also be 'planned date' or something.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the highest value of **today**, then you can use:

```
SELECT MAX(value)
FROM MyTable
WHERE CAST(DateTime AS DATE) = CURRENT_DATE
```

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough. I don't mean the highest value of today. I mean the highest value of the whole day with the highest datetime. That day could be today, that day could be yesterday and day that could be the day last week.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just do this?

```
SELECT MAX(Value)
FROM MyTable
WHERE DateTime IN (
    SELECT MAX(DateTime)
    FROM MyTable
)
```

Comment: I think he wants the last value from yesterday(_"from the last day"_).

Comment: What happens if there are several values in the last day?

Comment: @OtoZars: It should select the largest value of the last day.

Comment: @voithos: It selects the Last not the Largest value. If the largest value has smaller DateTime then it is not selected.

Comment: @OtoZars: Then I have misunderstood what you are asking. You said "I need to select max value from the last day (newest) day." What does that mean? What is the "last day"?